# Android Structure

Tags: android, structure

### MORE INFO

I have doubts about the Android Structure of an App I´m trying to develop, I´m not expert, just an amateur and curious guy.

**I GOT CLEAR ANSWERS FROM YOU GUYS AND I´M SO THANKFUL FOR IT. I HAVE BEEN DOING IT RIGHT, JUST NEED SOMEONE WHO TELL ME SO.**

- structure -

  - **MainActivity** - ButtonA - ButtonB - ButtonC - ButtonD - ButtonE - Button F

    - **ActivityA** - ButtonA1 - ButtonA2 - ButtonA3 - ButtonA4
    - **ActivityB** - ButtonB1 - ButtonB2 - ButtonB3 - ButtonB4
    - **ActivityC** - ButtonC1 - ButtonC2 - ButtonC3
    - **Settings** - Name - Date - Numbers -

      - Layouts: **GOT IT RIGHT**
      - Function:  **READY TO GO**

#### THIS IS WHAT I´M TRYING TO DO

-Each button of each activity (above) start a short DrawableAnimation of 30 images tops.

-Each DrawableAnimation repeat itself continuously.

#### QUESTIONS

- The App start without problems, each button start a new DrawableAnimation without problem, but The App don´t clean the memory used after finish one DrawableAnimation, so sometimes I get the Out of Memory Error, How can I fix this? Is there a way to clean memory after one DrawableAnimation and before a new one starts?
- When a DrawableAnimation Start on an Activity different that the MainActivity (second, third, etc) return to the MainActivity or quit because the Out of Memory Error. What is happening here?
- The App have to record how many times a Button is click, how can I do this?

#### CODE TO START EACH DRAWABLEANIMATION

```
private void addListenerOnButton() {
    view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startanimation);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            frameAnimation.stop(); frameAnimation = null;
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation01);
            frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
```

I try to stop or clean memory using frameAnimation.stop(); frameAnimation = null; but it does´t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Yes, MainActivity is the default activity, but you can change your "launcher" activity in your AndroidManifest file. The line below defines the launcher activity

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

However, it should not be "MainActivity.xml", but "activity_main.xml", because Android's convention is sensitive about letter cases. The java file is "MainActivity.java". If you want a new screen, you should create a new activity(e.g. SecondActivity.java) with its layout(e.g. activity_second.xml). There are also alternative ways to change the screen, for example hiding and showing new views in single layout file but they are more advanced.

2.You can start a new activity from the current activity. For example, if you want to start `SecondActivity` from `MainActivity`, first you should declare the intent;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
```

Then start this;

```
startActivity(intent);
```

You can locate this for example in an `setOnClickListener` method.

3.Not so sure what you wanted in this one.

Answer (score 0):

Another rank amateur here ... If you're working in a development environment such as Eclipse, you can "make a new activity" and the layout will be at least started for you, but yes, each new screen will need its own xml file for the layout.

To go to another activity, you will need to use `Intent` per   http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html and each `Activity` will need its own Java file.

Your third bullet point doesn't seem to be a question, so I won't try to answer it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make things in a right way, you should:
1) Learn from the free, avaialble, easy to find sources (in your case it's  https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html).
2) Gain some experience, by writing code, writing code and writing more code.
3) If you will meet any difficulties while writing code (unexpected output, exceptions and e.t.c.) you should ask the question here while showing your code.

Good luck.

P.S.: You will not find a private teacher on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you bro, I´m not looking for a private teacher, only clarify some doubts. I´m doing well...